# How to clear User's Programs Menu folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am trying to create an setup project in visual studio 2010 that clears an existing applications program menu.  After running the installer that I am creating, the installer duplicated already existing short cuts in the programs menu. I would like to be able to remove all the existing short cuts from a specific programs menu folder and just have the new short cuts appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on Deployment project, select properties and set the "RemovePreviousVersion" property to true..